# Unable to return value from Promise.then javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using a Promise function to facilitate an ajax call. When I console log the 'value.bal' value from the server within the then function the expected value shows up in the console, but when I return it console.log it outside the then function the result is 'object Promise'. What am I missing?

```
    var promiseObject = SomefullfilledPromise;
    var result = promiseObject.then(function(value){
       console.log(value.bal); //expected value
       return value.bal;
    });
    console.log(result); //'object Promise'
```

Comment: Just use then in the calling function instead of making an anonymus.

Comment: order of operations, the code doesn't wait on the promise to finish before moving on to the console.log so the object you are logging is an unresolved promise

Comment: Related: [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = promiseObject.then(function(value){
       console.log(value.bal); //expected value
       return value.bal;
    });
```

would return a promise you can access the result of this promise in a .then()

```
.then((val) => {
    console.log(val)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That just repeats the ".then" portion of what I have. The problem is I can't get the "value.bal" piece out of the promise object to use in the rest of my code.

Comment: @AppreciateCo it's because that's not what you are supposed to do

Comment: you cannot access asynchronous code synchronously, you would have to resolve the variable or pass it in a callback

Comment: So I have to do whatever I need to do with the result form within the 'then' function. I get it. These function are tricky little guys. Thank you!